# Coverflow for mac os

Tags: cocoa, macos, coverflow

Is their any apple sample code to implement coverflow in MacOS. Apple core animation documentation shows example of coverflow. But I could not find related sample code. Parden me if I overlooked.

-Thanks in advance
shakthi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There it is: http://macindie.com/2009/12/mbcoverflowview-an-open-source-cover-flow-implementation-for-macosx/

Comment: Hi,
 I used above sample in my game. Where I render on NSOpenGLView. Cover flow getting drawn along with green patches.

Is it possible Core animation and OpenGL simultaneously?